# Having trouble drawing an image in Qt using QGraphicsScene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene, qpixmap, qlabel, qgraphicspixmapitem

1. The code below loads an image using QLabel. The code uses:   myLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask()); and it works as it should. The problem comes when I try and load an image using QGraphicsScene.

   ```
   #include <QApplication>
   #include <QLabel>
   #include <QtGui>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);
      QLabel myLabel;
      QPixmap pixmap("/path/tomy/image.jpg");
      myLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
      myLabel.setMask(pixmap.mask());

      myLabel.show();

      return app.exec();
   }
   ```
2. In this code I am attempting to the same as above but using QGraphicsScene. The pixmap is loaded properly, after that I am not sure why the program is not working properly. Is it because there is no setMask() operation?  Or is there an operation missing that is needed to make the image visible?

   ```
   #include <QtGlobal>


   #if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
      #include <QtWidgets>
   #else
      #include <QtGui>
   #endif

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
   {
      QApplication a(argc, argv);
      QPixmap pixmap("/path/tomy/image.jpg");
      QGraphicsPixmapItem item( pixmap);
      QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
      scene->addItem(&item);
      QGraphicsView view(scene);

      view.show();

      return a.exec();
   }
   ```

Comment: use scene->addPixmap() and add your pixmap directly

Comment: What do you mean by "the program is not working properly"?  Do you see the image at all?  The code shown works as expected for me.

Comment: Works for me too.